# How to add a 360 Image View in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to fit a normal image to a 360 image viewer in the Universal Windows Application, Windows 10.

How I can do this using basic controls? I tried implementing a hub to solve this, but failed to get the continuous flow of the image. (start of the image to the end of the image connected)

```
    <Hub>
        <HubSection >
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="sample.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

    </Hub>
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried using a hub and a scrollviewer, but yet could not get that continuous view.. Hub seems to do the trick if I can build that continuous flow of the image. (start of the image and the end of the image to be connected)

Comment: Please read the link I posted. Please add example code in your question. No one here will do all the job for you

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.. I've added the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

After few alterations.. I have managed to build a solution suffice to my task. I used a `ScrollViewer` with `ViewChanged` event handled. My Code is as follows.

```
        <ScrollViewer Name="scroll" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ViewChanged="scroll_ViewChanged">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="500">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Name="img1" Grid.Column="0" Source="sample.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Name="img2" Grid.Column="1" Source="sample.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Name="img3" Grid.Column="2" Source="sample.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

the `ViewChanged` event method as follows

```
        private void scroll_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var horizontalOffset = scroll.HorizontalOffset;
            var maxHorizontalOffset = scroll.ScrollableWidth; //sv.ExtentHeight - sv.ViewportHeight;


            if (maxHorizontalOffset < 0 ||
                horizontalOffset == maxHorizontalOffset ||
                horizontalOffset == 0)
            {
                // Scrolled to end or scrolled to the begining
                scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(2000);
            }
            else
            {
                // In the middle, do nothing
            }
        }
```

the `PageLoaded` event as follows,

```
        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            img1.Height = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight;
            img1.Width = 2000;
            img2.Height = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight;
            img2.Width = 2000;
            img3.Height = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight;
            img3.Width = 2000;
        }
```

Eventhough this may not be the best solution, it worked for me. Hope it helps.